# I can't install some software in my Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

I tried install UNetbootin. On the project [site](https://unetbootin.github.io/linux_download.html) is written:

> To install UNetbootin from the Ubuntu PPA, run the commands:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gezakovacs/ppa  
> sudo apt-get update  
> sudo apt-get install unetbootin
> ```

I completed the first two steps, and in the third step I have this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree  
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have  
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable  
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
unetbootin : Depends: libqt4-network (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable  
              Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.7.0~beta1) but it is not installable  
              Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.5.3) but it is not installable  
              Depends: p7zip-full but it is not installable  
              Depends: syslinux but it is not installable  
              Depends: syslinux-common but it is not installable  
              Recommends: extlinux but it is not installable  
              Recommends: unetbootin-translations but it is not going to be installed  
              Recommends: gksu but it is not installable or  
                          kdesudo but it is not installable  

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I tried to install Lutris to [run GTA 5 via Epic games](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/gk2j6n/gaming_on_linux_gta_5_working_properly_via_epic/) and I get a similar message:

```
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree   
Reading state information... Done  
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have  
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable  
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created  
or been moved out of Incoming.  
The following information may help to resolve the situation:  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  
lutris : Depends: python3-evdev but it is not installable  
          Depends: python3-setproctitle but it is not installable  
         Depends: cabextract but it is not installable  
        Depends: p7zip but it is not installable  
       Depends: fluid-soundfont-gs but it is not installable  
          Depends: mesa-utils but it is not installable  
          Recommends: libwine-development but it is not installable           Recommends: winetricks but it is not installable  
         Recommends: libc6-i386 but it is not installable  
         Recommends: lib32gcc1 but it is not installable  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Like the other case I need to add a ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lutris-team/lutris  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install lutris
```

To solve the problems I tried [Remove a PPA on Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/12/how-to-remove-ppa-ubuntu), [Restore your Sources List to Defaults in Ubuntu](http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/01/restore-your-sources-list-to-defaults.html), [How to fix a broken Ubuntu without reinstalling it (in portuguese)](https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/consertar-um-ubuntu-quebrado/) and nothing works.

Comment: Do you have 'universe' enabled?  I picked on package and it's found in universe (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/python3-evdev)  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  The held packages messages could mean prior commands that haven't been fixed yet, `sudo apt -f install` and check your sources (`apt update`; do you have non-focal sources?)

Comment: I verified. The unetbootin message continue.